Form of wide-band limit for the broadening
When considering the Green's function (GF) of a system coupled to a reservoir, the wide-band limit (WBL) is often assumed to simplify the discussion.
For instance, the reservoir retarded GF reads $g_k(\omega)=\frac{1}{\omega-\epsilon_k+i\eta}$ for its eigenstates labelled by $k$. It is coupled to some of the states of the central system labelled by $\alpha$ via a potential $v_{\alpha k}$ and its Hermitian conjugate $v_{k\alpha}$. Then the system retarded self-energy matrix is $$\Sigma_{\alpha\beta}(\omega)=\sum_k v_{\alpha k}\, g_k(\omega)\, v_{k\beta}. \qquad(*)$$
The WBL is an approximation that says one can set $$\Sigma_{\alpha\beta}(\omega)=-\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}$$ with a constant broadening $\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}$. However, it is not very clear what matrix form that $\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}$ should take for practical calculations. Since it is an approximation, explicit calculation does not seem to be able to specify the matrix form. Instead, we probably need some physical argument or intuition.
If there is only one relevant system state $\alpha$, it reduces merely to a number. This is the case for a single-level problem like in textbooks and some papers (e.g., p20 of this one).
But when the system is more than 1D and coupled to leads, even one interface of the system consists certainly of multiple sites/states labelled by $\alpha$. If we have transport calculations in mind, e.g., a system coupled to electrodes, let's say $\alpha,\beta$ belong to the sites of the central system's interface with one particular electrode and forget about other electrodes. In such a case, should we set $$\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}=\gamma\delta_{\alpha\beta}$$ for a constant $\gamma$? From (*) above, it seems reasonable to not assume $\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}=0$ when $\alpha\neq\beta$ for generic couplings. Then shall we use something like $$\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}=\gamma \quad \forall \alpha,\beta$$ or else? Unfortunately, I don't find any explicit discussion about this.

This seems very similar to your other question - you only need to redo the calculation for a system with multiple states.

@RogerV. They are different questions. Here, I'm asking about a certain type of approximation. The calculation can be done to the extent I show. The rest is making a good approximation.

I don't understand what you ask - you already have the matrix. BBL is assuming that $v_{k,\alpha}$ are independent on $k$. You then carry out summation in $\Sigma$.

Actually, it is not clear whether your index $\alpha$ refers to states in the central region or the leads... generally, you have both indices.

@RogerV. Yes, we know it is a matrix. I'm asking, if we want to do some practical calculation, what pattern of values should the matrix entries take. If it is merely a number, one can simply put some numerical value. But if it is a matrix, maybe assuming some pattern is better than assuming others. Like I mentioned, a diagonal one or a fully uniform one, which is better in practical calculation?

@RogerV. $\alpha$ is for the 'system' (central region) in a system+reservoir setting.

The specific choice depends on the problem that you are dealing with. E.g., Meir&Wingreen in their original paper use proportional coupling to reservoirs, which allows to exclude the $G^<$. But this doesn't work for AB interferometers, where the phases of $\Gamma_{\alpha,\beta}$ around a closed path should sum to the magnetic flux.Some Coulomb charging effects are described by a combination of thin and broad levels - in short, it is about the physics of the problem, not about the math.

Typically tunneling matrix elements are characterized not only by the index of state within the "interacting" region $\alpha$, but also the index of the lead from/to which the tunneling occurs $\nu$, that is
$$
\Sigma_{\alpha\beta}^{(\nu,\nu')}(\omega)=\sum_k v_{\alpha k\nu}\, g_k(\omega)\, v_{k\beta\nu'}
$$
(In the OP this index could be implied in $k$, but it is worth writing explicitly.)
In the broad-band limit this degenerates into
$$
\Sigma_{\alpha\beta}^{(\nu,\nu')}(\omega)=-\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^{(\nu)}\delta_{\nu,\nu'}
$$
Actually, the self-energy entering the Green's function of the "interacting/central" region is summed over $\nu$, but the explicit lead index appears in the matrix factors describing the coupling to the leads, which enter expressions for transport coefficients.
Where do coefficients $\Gamma$ come from?
In general, $\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}^{(\nu)}$, just like level energies are determined by solving the appropriate Schrödinger equation prior to dealing with the transport problem. Moreover, the transfer Hamiltonian, describing uncoupled central region and leads as separate quantum regions, between which electrons hop, is itself an approximation or even a phenomenological ansatz. Thus, the broadenings $Gamma$ are phenomenological parameters, with the orders of magnitide best inferred experimentally, and relative magnitudes and phases determined by the physical problem itself.
In other words - our focus here is not on exactly determining the magnitudes of the parameters, but on modeling/describing transport phenomena. This is a completely general approach, and deserves a special remark: although physics prides itself in being quantitative science and making quantitative predictions, it should not be understood as carrying out exact first principles calculations when engineering devices - in fact, such calculations are unwieldy and often unrealistic, because measuring all the underlying parameters is technically very difficult, even if theoretically possible.
General approaches to $\Gamma$s

The original paper by Meir, Wingreen, and Lee and many publications that followed assumed "proportionate" coupling to leads, i.e., broadenings with different indices $\Gamma$ differed only by a scalar coefficient, but otherwise were identical matrices. This allowed reducing the description of transport to calculating only the retarded Green's function $G^r$, which allowed producing a number of spectacular results. Generally calculations are more difficult and require full-fledged Green's function calculations to determine the "lesser" Keldysh Green's function $G^<$.
A notable place where the "proportionate" coupling approach is impossible is when describing Aharonov-Bohm interferometers - since the broadenings need to have complex phases, modeling the magnetic flux. Example of such a calculation, from the same group, are here and here.
Some problems describing Coulomb charging effects in quantum dots may require assigning big $\Gamma$ to some levels and small ones to other. In principle, this does not preclude the use of proportionate coupling. But since such problems are often studied using behavior of QDs inserted in AB rings, the previous comment applies.


Thank you for the discussion and references. Most of them either use proportionate coupling or just a simple number $\Gamma$. Only this one linked by you seems to have an explicit matrix $\Gamma_{\alpha\beta}$ defined below Eq. (1). However, from the caption of Fig. 2, it seems to specify only diagonal elements and probably just assuming a diagonal form as I mentioned. It's not clear how this is justified (hopping from QD1 to lead to QD2 seems always possible). Or maybe it's merely an approximation to simplify calculation?

@xiaohuamao if you read the paper, their tunneling matrix is definitely non-diagonal. However, as far as magnitudes are concerned $|\Gamma_{12}|=|\Gamma_{21}|=\sqrt{\Gamma_{11}\Gamma_{22}}$ - this readily follows from the definition of self-energy and $\Gamma$ in your question and the answer above. It is the AB phase that make the couplings non-proportionate: $1\neq e^{i\phi}$.

Thank you for the clarification.
